# ¿Por qué no me funciona un == en un if?

Tags: php, condiciones

Estoy enviando datos desde un juego de Unity que tiene un formulario, en el que se debe enviar un nombre de usuario.
Lo recibo correctamente, pero a la hora de comparar el valor recibido con un string idéntico no me entra aunque sean iguales.

```php
$user=$_POST["user"];
if($user=="admin")
{
//Codigo del if 
}else
{
print("admin==".$user);
}
```

Me entra siempre en el `else`, incluso cuando le mando como user "admin" me entra en el `else` y me imprime: `admin==admin`

He probado a poner
`$user=(string)$_POST["user"];` y `$user=strval($_POST["user"]);` pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137324/discussion-on-question-by-miguel-por-que-no-me-funciona-un-en-un-if).

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de como recibir los datos enviados a un **Script de PHP**, pueda que el dato no este llegando o tus comprobaciones son erroneas, por eso la importancia de verificar desde un principio si el dato esta llegando y una forma de hacerlo es con *isset*. Dime si funciono.

**PHP**:

```js
<?php
//COMPROBAMOS LA LLEGADA DEL DATO
if(isset($_POST['user'])){
    //GUARDAMOS EL DATO RECIBIDO
    $user = $_POST['user'];

    //COMPARAMOS CON LAS CONDICIONALES
    if($user == 'admin'){
        echo 'Es Admin';
    }else if($user == 'player'){
        echo 'Es un jugador';
    }else{
        echo 'ninguno';
    }
}
?>
```